# Write byte sequence to file via command line?

Tags: linux, dump, hexadecimal

What's the quickest way to write a sequence of bytes from the commandline into a file? For example consider an input string in the following format:

```
DE AD BE EF
```

How can I write this to a file, so that the output file consists exactly of these 4 bytes? Of course I could write a python script to do it, but maybe there is a quick way directly over the command line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604765/how-to-convert-hex-to-ascii-characters-in-the-linux-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo -en '\xde\xad\xbe\xef' | hexdump -C
00000000  de ad be ef                                       |....|
00000004
$
```

Replace `| hexdump -C` with `> path/to/file` to write to a file (or `>>` to append to a file).

If you have a file of a sequence, you can do this to "convert" it:

```
$ cat test
DE AD BE EF
DE AD BE EF
$ for i in $(cat test); do echo -en "\x$i"; done | hexdump -C
00000000  de ad be ef de ad be ef                           |........|
00000008
$
```

Comment: This not writing to a file as the asker requests. He may not know how to modify your commands.